# Ionic backbutton even return isTrusted:false

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing application using ionic framework and i want to do some action on back button.
so i used it as

```
$ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(function(e) {
      /*  some actions */
      e.preventDefault();
})
```

But `preventDefault`  is not working, so for debugging i alert `e` and i got the result as

```
{isTrusted:false}
```

I also tried cordova backbutton action and alert e:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
      alert(JSON.stringify(e));
})
```

This is also returning `{"isTrusted":false}`
Anyone know how to solve it? why event within function is returning Trusted:false ?

Comment: `$ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });` try this

Comment: but e is returning isTrusted:false then how stopPropagation will works?

Comment: and i already tried this..then i check alert(JSON.stringify(e)). but e is not working so e.anyfunction() will now work.

Comment: Alert cannot show functions, because stringify strips functions, as it's not valid JSON format, definitely it has stopPropagation!, try using tricks to check it out

Comment: You if are using android-monitor, then you could use console.log and catch the event's value. As i recall, there is also a ios debugger with logging

Comment: as i told to i already tried stopPropagation. and event e is json format so we can definitely alert as a JSON.stringify.

Comment: `{a: function(){}, e: {}}` JSON.strinfigy will result in `{"a": {}}`